# PHP url keeps stacking through folder

Tags: php, html, css

While trying to access pages from folder my url keeps stacking one after another rather than going to appropriate page.
This is my directory structure.

```
Website/
    css/
    js/
    includes/
        header.php
        footer.php
        helper.php
    sub-folder/
        foo.php
    index.php
```

after going to `localhost/sub-folder/foo.php` it goes to `localhost/website/sub-folder/foo.php/index.php` instead of `localhost/website/index.php`

This causes error even when loading css from foo.php which connects via header.php

This is my header.php

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Chili Pili</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS only -->
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/imagehover.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/utils.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css"></link>
    <style>
        li{
            font-size:20px;
        }
        .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover .dropdown-menu .dropdown-item:hover {
        color: var(--color1) !important;
        }
        .active{
        color: var(--color1) !important;
        border-bottom:2px solid var(--color1);
        border-width:20%;
        text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
```

foo.php

```
<?php
include '../includes/header.php'
?>


<?php
include 'includes/footer.php'
?>
```

What can be done so urls don't keep stacking and return correct url so css file can be accessed from foo.php. Currently due to stacking its impossible to retrieve css files

Answer (score 0):

In header.php `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/imagehover.min.css">` will link file header.php/css/imagehover.min.css.
try to add a `/` in front of `css` like so `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/website/css/imagehover.min.css">`

Comment: Doing it this way css file doesn't link properly. and url for becomes `localhost/css/style.css` instead of 'localhost/website/css/style.css' the header.php is linked to index.php and all other pages who want to access the header section.

Comment: In this case try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/website/css/imagehover.min.css">`